# How to replace a line of code that is generated from a database in order to populate a page based on user selection

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I have a website that has a catalog consisting of a number of items.  Each item is populated from a database.

I want to be able to change the content of a page based upon what the user clicks.  Difficult to explain what I mean.

So far i have this:

```
<section id="images" style="width:400px; float:left; height:auto;">

    <p><?php $load_content->load_content('1001');?></p>
```

Basically I want to use jquery to change the '1001' to '1002'.  I can do this manually myself and it changes the content appropriately.  However I want to set it so as if a user clicks on an item that contains any number between 1001-1024 then the appropriate images are loaded.  If you get my meaning.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You'll either need some kind of webservice that you call which then replaces the content, or you could use `GET` vars and request a new page (but you wouldn't need javascript for this, a normal link would do it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

You must understand that the php is server side while the jquery (javascript) is client side. So the PHP is executed on the server, before it reaches the browser, while the jquery is only executed in the browser itself. Hence, you can't go back and change the value of 1001 to 1002.

So you're only options are AJAX or refreshing the page.

Edit:

The above is the answer to the question, but in reality, You can easily load images using javascript and jquery, you don't need PHP for that.

Comment: That is exactly what I thought, is there anyway to accomplish what I want?

Comment: Its good that you have the concept, so really its ajax or refreshing the page. If you give me a js fiddle with your jquery or something I may be able to give you a better idea

Comment: you can easily load images using javascript and jquery, you don't need PHP for that...

Comment: The other answer will be much slower than just simply using jquery

Comment: I need to use PHP to populate the content of the site because the entire thing is controlled by a content management system that I built.  If a user replaces an image in the database, the images throughout the site will automatically change.  I could build a separate page for each catalog listing but I wanted to be able to generate this page depending on user selection.

Comment: so if I get you, a user can click on a button and that changes the image throughout the site for everyone? Well, in that case, use ajax asynchronously. there's still some issues there in terms of the change (if there is any) won't be immediate for the user until they refresh, you need to use JS for that.

Comment: Im going to have to look into ajax then because I have never used it.  I think you following me.

Comment: What I have is a catalog that has 24 items.  If an item is clicked on it opens another page that has more details about the item plus larger pictures etc.  Instead of building 24 different pages, one for each item.  I simply wanted to generate the content of that 1 page based on what item has been clicked on.  I can do this in jQuery but because the images and data are in a database this no longer works.

Comment: okay so you've two choices. 

1) When the page loads first with the 24 buttons, pass along the links to the images and the data. This needs to be stored but there's a variety of ways of doing that. This would be far quicker but a little more painful.

Comment: 2) When the user clicks on the button, use AJAX or just a normal request to the server asking for the specific data and images depending on what the user has clicked on. This would be slower but easier.

Comment: I like the second, it'll be a little slower because you're making 2 requests, but it'll be easier for you to code

Comment: so build something that takes in a GET param such as id (which will be between 1001 and 1024) and which returns back the images and data (JSON would be best) get me?

Comment: then either link to it directly or use AJAX. Hope that all helps and if you've questions just ask.

Comment: Yes I think thats exactly what I need.  Now il just do a bit of research on this and attempt it.  Thank you

Comment: great. just say if you need a hand.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not even going into the detail of how you are choosing to display your data.
While you can't use jQuery to replace a line of PHP Code, I think what you want is either GET or POST, to get that data from a specific php file and load it dynamically without having to leave or refresh the page.

So Here is an example of $.ajax, which is equivalent to get.

```
`$.ajax({
url: url,
data: data,
success: success,
dataType: dataType
});`
```

A usage example:

```
`$.get("yourpage.php", { id: 2002 }, function(data) {  
alert("Your new content: " + data);  
});`
```

Then you insert the content into a div or something, by placing the following line in side the function, such as:

`$('#your_target_div').html(data);`

Comment: all he wants to do is load an image, there's no need for any server side involvement here seemingly

Comment: No thats not what I am trying to do.  I have built a full content management system that populates a catalog with data and images.  I want to use jquery or something similar show specific images depending on what the user clicks.  As the images will be changed from time to time it is not suitable to use html or jquery if you follow

Comment: The answer is still valid. You can get partial results, or an entire webpage, and just populate a div, or replace your entire webpage. To your choosing, fit your code to what fits you best.